# Connecting Two Linux System via Serial

Tags: linux, serial-port, freebsd

I would like to connect two Unix Flavored System through Serial port. Can some one shed some light on this pleasE?

On one Machine I have a freeBSD installed and the other Machine I have installed Fedora 15.

The FreeBSD is where I will be initiating the connection and Fedora will be accepting the connection.

I have changed the run level on my Fedora so that It stops at command line. (i.e., set the run level to 3).

Both the Machines have com POrts (Male) and I connect them back to Back via Serial Cable (Both end Female Connectors)

Now from the FreeBSD Machine, I initiate a connection but i dont see the connection getting successful

I have disabled Firewall on my Fedora 15.

Comment: I cannot use LAN CAble because the script that I run will reboot the machine. When the machine is rebooted, I might loose connection when I use IP address and LaN Cable.

Comment: So you really don't want IP networking. You want a serial console on the one machine, which comes back when the machine is rebooted, and through which you can send commands from the other machine, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need a "null modem" cable (or adapter), which crosses certain pairs of RS-232 lines. A straight pinout cable won't work because that will connect, for instance, CTS to CTS and RTS to RTS rather than CTS to RTS and vice versa.

Do you have a null modem adapter or cable in the connection chain?

Once you have a null modem, the next step is to verify the connectivity. This can be done in a number of ways. For instance, running a serial communications program such as Minicom on both ends, setting up the communication parameters (baud, bits, parity, handshaking ...) and seeing whether you can type characters on one side and have them appear on the other.

(You can also use `stty < /dev/tty<whatever> <args>` to view/change serial parameters, and `echo` and `cat` can be used.)

When the data link is thus working, you can think about setting up IP communication (other answer given).